# No loaders configured for node_modules | webpack + babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I am trying to load a JSX Component from a module declared as a devDependency in my project. However, upon running webpack, I get the below error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (70:20)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. 

|
|                 render(
>                     <Provider store={store}>
|                         <MyApp />
|                     </Provider>,
 @ ./src/App.js 48:43-96
 @ ./src/index.js
```

I am using webpack 4 and babel 7.

webpack dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",
    "dummy-pkg": "file:../dummy-pkg",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.16.1",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.40.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"
}
```

webpack config:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            include: [path.resolve(__dirname, './src'), /node_modules\/dummy-pkg/],
            use: 'babel-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        }
    ]
 }
```

babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

When I try to import the Component from `dummy-pkg`, it fails with the error message that I have mentioned above.

If I remove the import, all the other JSX components that have been declared within my current project are transpiled correctly. Introducing this causes all the problems.

I have been looking at a lot of other questions on Stack Overflow as well as some GitHub issues. The solutions suggested there do not seem to work out for me.

Any help would be really appreciated.
TIA!

**UPDATE**

After some more debugging, I found that you need to define the babel config in `babel.config.json`

More info available [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/configuration#whats-your-use-case). Other File types are listed [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#configuration-file-types)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly what I have noticed is that when you are providing the `presets` in `.babelrc` it's not working if there's anything that you want exclude from `node_modules` but when I placed the presets in my `webpack.config` it worked like gem. So I would suggest to try keeping the rule for `js or jsx` like below and test

```js
{
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    exclude: [/node_modules\/dummy-pkg/],
    use: {
      loader: "babel-loader",
      options: {
         presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
         plugins: [
           "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
         ]
       }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That worked for me. Thanks a lot!! Any idea why this happens. I could not find this on the babel documentation.

Comment: Even I couldn't find anything on the docs. Not sure why this is happening. But will surely update here if I find anything. 
It'll be my pleasure to help. :-)

Comment: I found the reason for this and have updated that in the question itself

Comment: I think there's an issue in babel itself. I found some discussion about the issue [here](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/552), please have a look. Might help

Comment: Oh, `babelrc` will act for that particular module only now. So if we want to apply it for the entire project then we might have to provide `global babel config` so that it'll be applied for all. Or we can also provide `babelrc` for each individual modules. Am I correct?

Comment: That's what it seems to me. And I suppose its more of a babel 7 thing because it seemed to work fine with babel 6 but there are some issues with that as mentioned in https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#6x-vs-7x-babelrc-loading which could have been the motivation behind such type of config

Comment: Yes. Even my understanding was the same. And Thank you for sharing more info about it. Much appreciated :-)